# Bevel (modifier) each individual vertex

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel

Is there a way (addon or similiar) to bevel vertices individually. The Bevel modifier clamps all vertices the same, I would like it to **clamp** each vertex individually.

This is the behaviour I would like to have.

[image]

This is the current behaviour. (The position of the edge loop on the left change the bevel on the right edge.) How can I avoid that?

[image]

[image]

Trying to word it better:
**How do I avoid dense geometry limiting the amount of bevel on all parts of the model?**

I would try other non-destructive methods except the bevel modifier as well.

[image]

Comment: Since groups are about vertices and so not edges, I don't think this is possible. Or do you mean beveling manually?

Comment: @Lemon 
I have corrected the post, I meant vertices, not edges.

Comment: Well... unclear to me as individual vertex cannot be beveled. Could you describe what you mean with the gif?

Comment: @Lemon I want to apply a bevel modifier and achieve this behaviour. (It may be another modifier or addon or script.) The edge loop on the left shouldnt affect the bevel width on the right.

Comment: Basically, it does not affect it. But as you said, this does not work for complex meshes... and I think this is because there is no 'edge groups' (and so vertex groups selects unwanted edges)

Comment: @lemon Sorry, I don't understand "Basically, it does not affect it." I have uploaded another image of the current behaviour. The edgeloop affects the bevel on the right.

Comment: Could you upload your file? (I can't reproduce here the last gif of last edit)

Comment: I'd say this won't work for Bevel modifier (unless specifying vertex groups or bevel weight) because of how it prevents intersecting. It clamps beveled edges all across the mesh if any one of them allows only tiny beveling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mention bevel per vertex but then you proceed to illustrate beveling per edge.
Not sure what you really want to achieve, sounds like what *Bevel Weights* are for.

Add a *Bevel* Modifier to your mesh object, for ease of mental calculations set its Bevel width to $1.0$, then proceed to turn off *Clamping* and set the *Limit Method* to *Weight*.

Then in *Edit Mode* on your mesh, select desired edges and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> *Edges > Edge Bevel Weight* to control the bevel width on a per-edge basis.

Edge weight acts a multiplication factor over the bevel distance, if you set bevel distance to a round number like $1.0$ it will facilitate adjustment. If now want a bevel of $0.5$ units just set the weight to $0.5$, if you want a bevel of $1$, $2$ or $3.7$ just set the weight to $1.0$, $2.0$ or $3.7$ respectively.

[image: Bevel Weights]